# How to send POST request to JSF with help HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, jsf

I send post request with body `login=login&login:loginName={0}&login:password={1}&login:clientCode=&login:j_idt171=&javax.faces.ViewState=stateless`
with help `HttpWebRequest`. Before that I was doing `GET` request, for getting `JSESSIONID`.
Web form looks like that:

```html
<form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="/csologin/login.jsf">
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="login">
<div id="login:j_idt122" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="580px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ecol1"><label id="login:j_idt125" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget fbold" for="login:loginName">Username<span class="ui-outputlabel-rfi">*</span></label></td>
            <td class="ecol2"><input id="login:loginName" name="login:loginName" type="text" autocomplete="off" size="40" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false"></td>
            <td class="ecol3"><div id="login:j_idt126" aria-live="polite" class="ui-message"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="580px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ecol1"><label id="login:j_idt132" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget fbold" for="login:password">Password<span class="ui-outputlabel-rfi">*</span></label></td>
            <td class="ecol2"><input id="login:password" name="login:password" type="password" class="ui-inputfield ui-password ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" autocomplete="off" size="40" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false"></td>
            <td class="ecol3"><div id="login:j_idt133" aria-live="polite" class="ui-message"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="580px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ecol1"><label id="login:j_idt135" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget fbold" for="login:clientCode">Client Code</label></td>
            <td class="ecol2"><input id="login:clientCode" name="login:clientCode" type="text" maxlength="32" size="40" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false"></td>
            <td class="ecol3"><div id="login:j_idt136" aria-live="polite" class="ui-message"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br><div class="text-center">
    <button id="login:j_idt139" name="login:j_idt139" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="barWaitDialog.show();" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Login</span></button>
    <!-- &lt;p:commandButton value="Clear" onclick="clearVisibleTextFields();" /&gt;  --><button id="login:j_idt141" name="login:j_idt141" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'login:j_idt141',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){clearVisibleTextFields();;}});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Clear</span></button><button id="login:j_idt142" name="login:j_idt142" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Cancel</span></button>
</div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="stateless" autocomplete="off">
```

Not authenticated, it returns a redirect to login page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you didn't press the desired button. You need to include the `name=value` pair of the submit button you'd like to "press" programmatically. That's usually in the server side used to distinguish if a button was pressed and if so, which one.

There appear to be three submit buttons in the HTML form, simplified as below:

```html
<button name="login:j_idt139" type="submit">Login</button>
<button name="login:j_idt141" type="submit">Clear</button>
<button name="login:j_idt142" type="submit">Cancel</button>
```

It appears that the JSF developer didn't give an explicit ID to those buttons, so an autogenerated ID is being used. This autogenerated ID depends on the position of the button component in the JSF component tree. So, if the JSF developer changes the view composition (adding/moving/removing components), then chances are that the final ID of the button in the HTML markup will also change. You'd need to alter your query string on that. The parameter `login:j_idt171=` in your query string likely needs to be changed to `login:j_idt139=`.

To make it more robust, you could try contacting the website admin/developer and ask to give those buttons an explicit ID as in `<p:commandButton id="login">`, so that you can always use the parameter `login:login=` without worrying about autogenerated IDs. If that's really not an option, then you'd basically need to use a HTML parser to find out the ID of the login button.

Comment: server will get parameter `login:j_idt139=`, even if value is empty?

Comment: In case of JSF, yes, just the presence of the request parameter name is sufficient. The value basically arrives as an empty string instead of null.